# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c# Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, registry, stack-trace

I am creating a program in Windows Services that I want to get values from a registry file and  put them into a struct database created in my program and then run it in a on start method.

Every time I try to run the program in services it starts and stops and when viewing the error messages in Event viewer I keep getting the message Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I reach a certain point in the method.

Here is where I create the registry method configuration. I have used an WriteToEventLog message at each part of the statement to see where it is not called:

```
      public static class ServerConfiguration
    {

        public static void GetServerConfiguration()
        {
            try
            {
                Logging.WriteToEventLog("1", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                RegistryKey mykey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE/PULSE/SERVER",false);
                Logging.WriteToEventLog("2", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                if (mykey != null)
                {
                    Logging.WriteToEventLog("3", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    string currentkey;
                    currentkey = mykey.GetValue("DBAUTH", "").ToString();
                    Logging.WriteToEventLog("4", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    if (currentkey != null)
                        Configuration.Database.trustedauth = Convert.ToBoolean(currentkey);

                    currentkey = mykey.GetValue("DBNAME", "").ToString();
                    Logging.WriteToEventLog("5", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    if (currentkey != null)
                        Configuration.Database.Databasename = Convert.ToString(currentkey);
                    currentkey = mykey.GetValue("DBPASSWORD", "").ToString();
                    Logging.WriteToEventLog("6", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    if (currentkey != null)
                        Configuration.Database.password = Convert.ToString(currentkey);
                    currentkey = mykey.GetValue("DBSERVER", "").ToString();
                    Logging.WriteToEventLog("7", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    if (currentkey != null)
                        Configuration.Database.Server = Convert.ToString(currentkey);
                    currentkey = mykey.GetValue("DBUSER", "").ToString();
                    Logging.WriteToEventLog("8", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                    if (currentkey != null)
                        Configuration.Database.username = Convert.ToString(currentkey);
                }

                mykey.Flush();
                mykey.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logging.WriteToEventLog("Message: " + ex.Message + "\nStack: " + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```

When I check the event viewer after I run it in Event Viewer it reaches EventLog number 3 but then stops after that and cannot reach string currentkey; on wards.

Here is where I call it in the OnStart method in the ServiceBase:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Configuration.ServerConfiguration.GetServerConfiguration();

    }
```

Would someone be able to help as to why it cannot reach the rest of the method in the configuration?

Comment: If it prints log #3 but not log #4, then i guess `mykey.GetValue("DBAUTH", "")` is null.

Comment: Maybe you run your program without admin permissions and the UAC is enabled on your machine? Try running your service with Local System account identity

Comment: Debug your service directly by calling `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch` at the beginning of your start method.  When you start your service, you should be given a dialog that lets you jump into a debug session.  You can step through the code normally from there.  AFWIW, the problem description sounds like you do not have enough permission to read from the registry.

Comment: it actually reaches log #2 and not log #3 on wards so now I really don't know why it's not working.

Comment: problem solved it seemed that the issue was that registry was case sensitive and required double slashes when setting mykey to Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey part.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure you'll always have a value for these key getvalue calls then I would do this:

```
currentkey = mykey.GetValue("DBAUTH", "") as String;
```

Then you can check currentKey for nulls.

and if that cast doesn't work then do this:

```
currentkey = (mykey.GetValue("DBAUTH", "") ?? "").ToString();
```

Then you can check to see if it's an empty string.  I haven't tested that, but that's the general logic.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas but unfortunately it still doesn't run and it actually only manages to reach log #2.

Comment: Problem solved it seemed that the issue was that registry was case sensitive and required double slashes when setting mykey to Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey part. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: @TireniDada you should write your comment as the answer and mark solved.